# Finding the right epsilon...

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $c_1,...c_d$ be real non-negatives constants (one of them must be strictly positives).

**Question:** Can we found an $\varepsilon > 0$, which will depend on $c_1,\ldots,c_d$, such that for all $t_1,\ldots,t_d \in \mathbb C$ such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^d c_i t_i = 1$,

$$\exists j \in 1,\ldots,d, \; s.t. \, \left\lvert \frac{t_j+1}{t_j-1} \right\rvert > 1+\varepsilon\, ?$$

Here, $\lvert . \rvert$ denotes the modulus of a complex.

If you want, I want to ensure that the componantwise mapping $t_j \mapsto \frac{t_j+1}{t_j-1}$ maps the hyperspace defined by the constants $c_1,\ldots,c_d$ somewhere farther than $1+\varepsilon$ for the origin (again, componantwise).

Do you have any idea on how to proove this ?

---

**Thoughts:** As a first start, I considered the Möbius transform $t_j \mapsto \frac{t_j+1}{t_j-1}$. It is its own inverse, and maps lines to circles (or lines). But it did not help me to turn the hyperspace constraint into a modulus constraint on the result..

---

**Numerical evidence:** As i was'nt sure that it was true, since i cannot proove the assertion, I coded [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66640006/how-can-i-minimize-this-function) an algorithm that looks for a counter-example, and i did not found one yet...

Comment: choose $c_1=c_2=1$ and $t_1=N, t_2=1-N$ for large $N$; then since $\frac{N+1}{N-1} \to 1$ and $0<\frac{N-2}{N}<1$ there is no $\epsilon$ that works for all such

Comment: Which is a good remark.. and also a problem for me. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: imho, you have to see exactly what the original problem needs - maybe you can restrict to a domain where you can find an $\epsilon$ as above

Comment: Well, the original problem is to make analytic a certain function in a disc around the origin, to apply Cauchy's inequality. This function is $f((t+1)/(t-1))$, where $f$ has these hyperplanes as singularities.